# Android Tablet Side Connector Interface Information

Tags: connector, interface, android

I'm not sure if this is on topic or not, but I'm trying to find out about the interface found on the side of some Android devices. An example can be found by side of the "pipo n2" device. It appears to consist of two groups of six pin receptors.

[image: Android tablet interface]

- Is this a standard interface for Android devices?
- Does this type of interface have a generic name?
- Is the pinout published for this interface?
- Are there standard docking stations available which utilise this interface?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to get power out (or in, but that's harder to test for), but I doubt you'll do more than that.

Comment: Questions on the *usage* and characteristics of *consumer products* are off-topic.  If this were an Android standard connection (which it is not) it would be documented on the Android developer pages.  The aspects of "dock" functionality which are standard are documented there, but that's mostly about the conceptual operation and less about the physical interface.  It's possible that proprietary interface does channel some documented standard ones, eg analog audio, or USB...

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a standard interface for android devices ?

No, very likely these connectors are only available in this shape on this particular model tablet. **Maybe** other tablets from the same manufacturer (Pipo) have it as well.

> Does this type of interface have a generic name ?

It depends what the interface is used for, if it connects to a docking stand it could be called a "docking connector".

> Is the pinout published for this interface ?

Probably not, you will have to ask the manufacturer: [Pipo](http://www.pipo.com/)

> Are there standard docking stations available which utilise this interface ?

Very likely not as to me it looks like this is the only tablet using that interface and it isn't even clear what it can be used for (in a quick search I could not find any accessories that would connect to this interface).

It is possible that Pipo added the connectors to make the tablet work with some accessory but then later decided not to bring out (sell) the accessory.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This type of connector appears to be a form of POGO connector. I've seen this on several devices out there but you are probably right that this configuration is no doubt bespoke and nongeneric. 

![POGO](https://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/P1090628-580x435.jpg)

Comment: Indeed it is a pogo type connector where the pins are spring-loaded and gold plated. Pogo only refers to the technology used to make the physical way to make an electrical connection, it doesn't say anything about the signal or power passed through the connector.